# How to have the effect of RecyclerView with CardView items using only one RecyclerView with itemDecorators?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have RecyclerView where each item represent CardView, and each CardView contain RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager or LinearLayoutManager,
I don't want to go with RecyclerView inside RecyclerView, want to have a one RecyclerView and to achieve the CardView effects(margins,elevations) using different viewTypes, or ItemDecorators. Is it the right approach? and samples could be useful.

Comment: cannot you use `ConstraintLayour` (or any other layout you want) as a container for your card view content?

Comment: @psknik I can use Constraitlayout inside Cardview ,but each cardview can contain more than 15-20 items, in that case do you thing Constraitlayout is a good idea? I want to have one Recyclerview with itemdecorstors like Cardview shadows

Comment: more means? 100? 1000? more? if it is just 20 items so i dont think this is a huge number

Comment: @psknik
now it's could be more 20 but after a while could become more than 100 ,in that case what we be done ?